# How do I match the widths of two tables in an email signature in Outlook?

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I am designing an HTML signature for a client, which needs to work in Outlook 365.

There are two main tables. The top table needs to be the same width as the bottom table.

The problem is I can't seem to align the logo (in the top table) with the right side of the bottom table. And the top table is narrower than the bottom one. I wish to make it the same width as the bottom table.

I want to keep it as much responsive as possible so that it can display properly on mobile displays.

Can you please suggest some solutions?

Thanks so much!

```html
<head>
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
@font-face
 {font-family:Calibri;
 panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */

a:link, 
 {color:#f67828;
 text-decoration:none;}
a:visited, 
 {color:#f6c228;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:bold;}
p
 {margin-top:0.0pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:3.0pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 text-align:justify;
 line-height:100%;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
 color:#808080;}

-->

/* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */

        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto;
        }

        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }

        /* What it does: A work-around for email clients meddling in triggered links. */
        *[x-apple-data-detectors], /* iOS */
        .x-gmail-data-detectors,  /* Gmail */
        .x-gmail-data-detectors *,
        .aBn {
            border-bottom: 0 !important;
            cursor: default !important;
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Prevents Gmail from displaying an download button on large, non-linked images. */
        .a6S {
            display: none !important;
            opacity: 0.01 !important;
        }
        /* If the above doesn't work, add a .g-img class to any image in question. */
        img.g-img + div {
            display:none !important;
           }

        /* What it does: Removes right gutter in Gmail iOS app: https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/issues/89  */
        /* Create one of these media queries for each additional viewport size you'd like to fix */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) { /* iPhone 6 and 6+ */
            .email-container {
                min-width: 375px !important;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
    <style>
        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid {
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }
            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }
            /* What it does: Adjust typography on small screens to improve readability */
          .email-container p {
            font-size: 13px !important;
            line-height: 24px !important;
          }
        }
      @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        .hide{display:none!important;}
        .block{display:block!important;}
  img.center-on-narrow {float:left !important;}
      }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table style="width:auto;">
 <tr>
  <td style="width:380px;padding-right:30px; display: inline-block;">
   <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
               <p style="color: #404040;"><strong>ADMIN USER</strong></p>
               <p style="color: #404040;">Business Manager</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/email-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />&nbsp;<a style="color: #808080;text-decoration:none;" href="mailto:doe@example.co.uk">nikki@example.co.uk</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/tel-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />&nbsp;4958695834</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/address-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />&nbsp;Demo Address</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/website-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />&nbsp;<a style="color: #808080;text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.example.co.uk">www.example.co.uk</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td style="width:auto; display: inline-block;">
   <table role="presentation">
    <tr>
     <td  dir="ltr" style="padding: 0px 0px 20px 10px;float:right !important;">
      <img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/example-logo-email.jpg" width="150" height="95" border="0" alt="alt_text" class="center-on-narrow" style="float:right; margin-top:15px;  max-width: 162px; height: auto; background: #e41433; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:80%;">
  <tr>
   <td style="border-bottom: 1pt solid #808080; border-top: 1pt solid #808080; padding-top: 10pt; padding-bottom: 10pt;">
    <p>Sign up to our <strong><a style="color: #808080;text-decoration:none;" href="http://example.com/gd-YnL">Newsletter</a></strong></p>
   </td>
   <td style="border-bottom: 1pt solid #808080; border-top: 1pt solid #808080; padding-top: 10pt; padding-bottom: 10pt; text-align:right;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/example"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/facebook-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/example"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/twitter-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com/example/"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/instagram-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/example-clinics/"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/linkedin_icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/exampleCoUk"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/youtube-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><p style="color: #808080; font-size: 11px;padding-top: 10pt; ">This e-mail including all attachments has been sent by example Aesthetics Ltd and is meant only for the intended recipient and may be a confidential communication or a communication privileged by law. If you received this e-mail in error, any review, use, dissemination, distribution, or copying of this e-mail is strictly prohibited. Please notify the sender immediately of the error by return e-mail and please delete this message from your system. Thank you in advance for your cooperation. Although we have taken steps to ensure that this email and attachments are free from viruses, we advise that in keeping with good computing practice the recipient must ensure that they are in fact virus free.</p></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

There were no error messages, but the tables are not matching in widths. The logo needs to align with the right side of the bottom table.

Answer (score 0):

There was a few things that needed changing.

- Your first table had a width auto meaning the width was dependent on its content. If the content was a word, the table would have taken its width.
- 2nd table had a width of 80% so both would have never been the same.
- What I did:

  - added an outer table
  - gave both the inner table 100% width.
  - Image table style was removed and aligned right

So now both tables will always be the same width. You can control the width of the signature using the width of the outer table.

```html
<head>
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
@font-face
 {font-family:Calibri;
 panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */

a:link, 
 {color:#f67828;
 text-decoration:none;}
a:visited, 
 {color:#f6c228;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:bold;}
p
 {margin-top:0.0pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:3.0pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 text-align:justify;
 line-height:100%;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
 color:#808080;}

-->

/* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */

        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto;
        }

        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }

        /* What it does: A work-around for email clients meddling in triggered links. */
        *[x-apple-data-detectors], /* iOS */
        .x-gmail-data-detectors,  /* Gmail */
        .x-gmail-data-detectors *,
        .aBn {
            border-bottom: 0 !important;
            cursor: default !important;
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Prevents Gmail from displaying an download button on large, non-linked images. */
        .a6S {
            display: none !important;
            opacity: 0.01 !important;
        }
        /* If the above doesn't work, add a .g-img class to any image in question. */
        img.g-img + div {
            display:none !important;
           }

        /* What it does: Removes right gutter in Gmail iOS app: https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/issues/89  */
        /* Create one of these media queries for each additional viewport size you'd like to fix */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) { /* iPhone 6 and 6+ */
            .email-container {
                min-width: 375px !important;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
    <style>
        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid {
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }
            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }
            /* What it does: Adjust typography on small screens to improve readability */
          .email-container p {
            font-size: 13px !important;
            line-height: 24px !important;
          }
        }
      @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        .hide{display:none!important;}
        .block{display:block!important;}
  img.center-on-narrow {float:left !important;}
      }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    
<table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        
          <table style="width:100%;">
 <tr>
  <td style="width:380px;padding-right:30px; display: inline-block;">
   <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
               <p style="color: #404040;"><strong>ADMIN USER</strong></p>
               <p style="color: #404040;">Business Manager</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/email-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />&nbsp;<a style="color: #808080;text-decoration:none;" href="mailto:doe@example.co.uk">nikki@example.co.uk</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/tel-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />&nbsp;4958695834</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/address-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />&nbsp;Demo Address</p>
               <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/website-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />&nbsp;<a style="color: #808080;text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.example.co.uk">www.example.co.uk</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td align="right" style="">
   <table align="right" role="presentation">
    <tr>
     <td  dir="ltr" style="padding: 0px 0px 20px 10px;float:right !important;">
      <img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/example-logo-email.jpg" width="150" height="95" border="0" alt="alt_text" class="center-on-narrow" style="float:right; margin-top:15px;  max-width: 162px; height: auto; background: #e41433; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
   <td style="border-bottom: 1pt solid #808080; border-top: 1pt solid #808080; padding-top: 10pt; padding-bottom: 10pt;">
    <p>Sign up to our <strong><a style="color: #808080;text-decoration:none;" href="http://example.com/gd-YnL">Newsletter</a></strong></p>
   </td>
   <td style="border-bottom: 1pt solid #808080; border-top: 1pt solid #808080; padding-top: 10pt; padding-bottom: 10pt; text-align:right;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/example"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/facebook-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/example"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/twitter-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com/example/"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/instagram-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/example-clinics/"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/linkedin_icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/exampleCoUk"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/youtube-icon.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><p style="color: #808080; font-size: 11px;padding-top: 10pt; ">This e-mail including all attachments has been sent by example Aesthetics Ltd and is meant only for the intended recipient and may be a confidential communication or a communication privileged by law. If you received this e-mail in error, any review, use, dissemination, distribution, or copying of this e-mail is strictly prohibited. Please notify the sender immediately of the error by return e-mail and please delete this message from your system. Thank you in advance for your cooperation. Although we have taken steps to ensure that this email and attachments are free from viruses, we advise that in keeping with good computing practice the recipient must ensure that they are in fact virus free.</p></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
        
        
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

    

</body>
```

Hope that is what you were after.